# Check contains of an alert using jQuery, then run function based on contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have a webform that has several required field. When I submit the form, my CMS automatically includes some JS Validation to check. Their validation looks something like this:

```
function checkWholeForm88517(theForm) {
   var why = "";
   if (theForm.CAT_Custom_1) why += isEmpty(theForm.CAT_Custom_1.value, "First Name");
   if (theForm.CAT_Custom_2) why += isEmpty(theForm.CAT_Custom_2.value, "Last Name");
   if (theForm.CAT_Custom_3) why += isEmpty(theForm.CAT_Custom_3.value, "Email Address");
   //etc.

   if (why != "") {
      alert(why);
      return false;
   }
}
```

When an alert pops up it will contain text like so:

```
- Please enter First Name
- Please enter Last Name
- Please enter Email Address
```

What I would like to do is run an if statement to see if the alert contains `- Please enter First Name` and if so, do something.

I tried doing this:

```
window.alert = function(msg) {

   if ($(this).is(':contains("- Please enter First Name")')) {
       $( ".error-msg" ).append('My Message...');
   }

}
```

Of course, this isn't working as I'm not exactly sure how to target the `msg` of the alert and check to see if it contains the text.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to treat the argument as a string and not the context object (`window`) as a DOM object.

```
if (msg.indexOf("some_substring") > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `this` likely refers to the `window` object. You need to test whether the `message` argument contains the string:

```
window.alert = function(message) {
  if (/- Please enter First Name/.test(message)) {
    $(".error-msg").append(message);
  }
}
```

Quentin already said that, but I wanted to mention that if you want to maintain or restore the original `.alert()` behavior, you can save a reference to the function:

```
var _defaultAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(message) {
  if (/- Please enter First Name/.test(message)) {
    $(".error-msg").append(message);
  }
  _defaultAlert.apply(window, arguments);
}
```